# Why postman not send data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm a beginner with nodejs and express. I'm trying to use postman's POST method but no data is getting sent. Here is my code

```
var express = require('express');

var userRouter = express.Router();
var userModel = require('../models/usermodels');

    userRouter.route('/users')

            .post(function(req,res) {
                var users = new userModel(req.body);
                users.name = req.body.name;
                users.age = req.body.age;
                users.save();
                res.status(200).send(users)
            })
```

Model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UsersSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    age:Number
});
var model = mongoose.model('Users',UsersSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

Where is my error?

Here is img
[image]

Comment: You need to share more information like how are you sending requests to your server and on which port you're running it.

Comment: @RohanKumar I'm use postman to send data and post 2912 . I added img . Can you help me ?

Comment: You're getting 200 response code. That means your server has sent response successfully.After `users.save()` i think it has returned the objectId of the document you inserted. Have you checked into your database whether the document was saved? What is your expected response?

Comment: `users.save();` is an async function. Give it a callback and inside that you can send out the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make sure that you define all configurations BEFORE defining routes.I think you define after  and it's reason why not work . If you do so, you can continue to use express.bodyParser().

Answer (score 0):

Use debugging using console.log and also use error callback on save

Also use **x-www-form-urlencoded** (Content type) option when sending data from postman

```
var express = require('express');

var userRouter = express.Router();
var userModel = require('../models/usermodels');

    userRouter.route('/users')    
            .post(function(req,res) {

                //check here if request receive
                 console.log("requessssssssssssssssssss");

                //check the data receive
                 console.log("dataaaaaaaaaaaaaa", req.body); 

                var users = new userModel(req.body);
                users.name = req.body.name;
                users.age = req.body.age;

                //check if any error 
                users.save(function(saveError){
                      if(saveError){
                       return  res.status(400).send(saveError)
                       }else{
                         res.status(200).send(users)
                       }
                });


            })
```

Comment: use x-www-form-urlencoded option when sending data from postman

Comment: I dont know why need send with form-urlencoded but I try and not work too

Comment: What console.log("dataaaaaaaaaaaaaa", req.body);  shows ?

Comment: I get underfine in console . Can you show me where is wrong in my  code ?

Comment: He's sending json file why need urlencoded ? I think he need body-parser to solved his problem